# Exception in convert method when closing the form during async task

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to visualize bubble sort in the following way: I have an array of textBoxes`arr[]` and on each iteration I highlight (by changing the backcolor to yellow) two elements of this array (to show the elements I'm working with now), wait 1.5 seconds, change places (if needed), wait again, and make backcolor white again. In order to wait 1.5 seconds I use `await Task.Delay(1500);`. Everything works fine, except when I don't want to wait until sorting finishes. When i click the close button during sorting, program throws an exception:

> *Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll
>   Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.***, showing on the line with `if (Convert.ToInt32(arr[j].Text) > Convert.ToInt32(arr[j+1].Text))`

But if I wait for the program to finish everything is ok.

Here is my code:

```
async private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int num = 0;//number of comparisons
        int swap = 0;//number of swaps

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int border = checkBox1.Checked ? (10 - 1 - i) : 9;//if checkBox1.Checked we use advanced bubble sort

            for (int j = 0; j < border; j++)
            {
                arr[j].BackColor = arr[j + 1].BackColor = Color.Yellow;

                num++;
                label3.Text = num.ToString();

                if (Convert.ToInt32(arr[j].Text) > Convert.ToInt32(arr[j+1].Text))
                {
                    label1.Text = arr[j].Text + " is grater than " + arr[j + 1].Text + "\n\nNumbers must \nbe changed";
                    await Task.Delay(1500);

                    swap++;
                    label4.Text = swap.ToString();

                    string temp = arr[j].Text;
                    arr[j].Text = arr[j + 1].Text;
                    arr[j + 1].Text = temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    label1.Text = arr[j].Text + " is smaller \nor equall to " + arr[j + 1].Text + "\n\nNumbers stay";
                }

                await Task.Delay(1500);
                arr[j].BackColor = arr[j + 1].BackColor = Color.White;
                if (checkBox1.Checked) arr[j + 1].BackColor = Color.Cyan;//elements that are already sorted (only in advanced bubble sort)
            }

            if (checkBox1.Checked) arr[0].BackColor = Color.Cyan;
            label1.Text = "Array is now sorted";
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Don't post here if you haven't debugged. Just look at the value that you're converting and it will be obvious why it's not in the correct format.

Comment: I did debug it, and everything works. I also checked the values I put as parameters in convert method. And everything is fine with that too. If there was a problem like this, it wouldn't be working at all. But it works perfectly, except when I close the form.

Comment: If you can't tell us what the value was that wasn't in the correct format then you haven't debugged. Debugging doesn't mean just running the program.

Comment: I know what debugging means. There is written in the code Convert.ToInt32(arr[j].Text). As I wrote, arr[] contains textBoxes and method textBoxt.Text returns a string. So logically, arr[j].Text is a string, and it is a usual parameter that goes to convert method

Comment: What is the value in arr[j].Text when it throws the exception?

Comment: Doesn't the .Text property always return a string?

Comment: Of course it always returns a `String`, but the error message is telling you that that `String` is not in the correct format, i.e. it doesn't represent a number, so `Convert.ToInt32` can't possibly work. If you haven't already looked at the value of that `String` then you don't know what debugging is, so you really ought to do some research and find out. There's no shame. No one knows what it is before they know. Now that you know that you don't know though, you should find out.

Comment: But it does convert that string. As I said, it works perfectly. It only throws the exception when I press the close button. I am also sure that this string represents a number, because when I create the form,  I fill all the textBoxes with numbers for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                arr[i].Text = Convert.ToString(rand.Next(10));
            }

Comment: Also, the method seems to be an async fire and forget method. When you close the form the method is continuing in the background, you might want look into passing a cancellation token and cancel the method before closing the form

Comment: Finally, that was a problem I was thinking about too. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may sound silly:

Is the CancelButton property of your form is assigned to the Button you've hooked this event?.

That's the only way this method will be called when closing the form by pressing ESC key.

Else

When the form is closed the textboxes are disposed which gradually sets their string to textBox.Text = "";

Now if you do

```
var value = Convert.ToInt32("");
```

Then you'll get System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' exception.

The best way to handle this situation as said in comments by Aman , have a cancellation token inside form close event and break your loop accordingly

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Assume that the async  method is running and ESC key is pressed, the controls become null since the form is closing and this method keeps accessing the controls to modify their properties, Tell me what happens now?

Comment: @OlegIvanytskyi: great , You can mark this as an answer if it solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

The easiest fix for this scenario would be to check if the form is still operational after the await. I.e.:

`await Task.Delay(1500);
 if(this.IsDisposed)
      return;`

However, using a BackgroundWorker and updating the UI through ProgressChanged callback would be an iteration towards a better approach.